Heroku Node.js app restarting with status 143: SIGTERM, MongoDB connection successful, AWS SDK v2 warning
I'm encountering an issue where my Node.js app on Heroku is restarting frequently with status 143 and receiving SIGTERM. MongoDB connects successfully, but the app keeps restarting. I also get a warning about AWS SDK v2 being in maintenance mode, though I'm not sure if that's related to the restarts. Memory usage is within limits
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// MongoDB Connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected successfully'))
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err.message);
    process.exit(1); // Exit process with failure
  });

// Graceful shutdown on SIGTERM
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('SIGTERM received. Shutting down gracefully...');
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Process terminated');
  });
});

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));


2024-10-06T22:54:59.108785+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB connected successfully
2024-10-06T22:55:00.017085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2024-10-06T22:55:01.365059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2024-10-06T22:55:01.440668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

MongoDB connects successfully.
Using process.env.PORT for dynamic port assignment.
Added error handlers for uncaught exceptions and unhandled rejections.
Receiving frequent Heroku dyno restarts with no clear error message.
